# How to call stored procedure with named parameters in mysql 8 without warnings?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Calling mysql 8 stored procedure with  named parameters :

```
call sp_getRefundedOrders(@in_productId := 1, @in_creatorId := 1, @in_operationType := 'PAYMENT_REFUNDED', @in_createdAtFrom := '2024-01-01', @in_createdAtTill := '2024-11-30' );
```

I got valid results from the server, but also I got a lot of warnings, like :

```
Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.
Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.
Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.
```

If I call stored procedure without  named parameters :

```
call sp_getRefundedOrders( 1, 1, 'PAYMENT_REFUNDED', '2024-01-01', '2024-11-30' );
```

I got valid results from the server and no warnings at all :

In which way can I use stored procedure with  named parameters in mysql 8 ?

Comment: What is the reason for to assign the values into user-defined variables in CALL statement? Do you use these variables in the procedure independently and need in save these values after SP is finished its work? This need is too strange.

Comment: @Akina, I do not neeed thes variables I just test in dbeaver and I want to make call with named parameters

Comment: *I want to make call with named parameters* There is no named parameters in MySQL. Absolutely! You simply assign the values into UDVs. The code which you have created simply creates independent session-scoped variables and assigns them the values.

Comment: It is true MySQL routines do not support named parameters. I think someone blogged about a "workaround" to mimic named parameters, by using the `:=` assignment operator. This does nothing to change the behavior of stored procedures, but in the procedure one can reference the user variable by name, and that variable happens to have the same value as the procedure parameter.

Comment: You can read more about this supposed workaround here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62151 The MySQL team considered it "not a bug."